# i want to select data when date between dd/mm/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I want to select data where date between dd/mm/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy

If the date in the same month I find data

For instance

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table Name 
WHERE date between '21/07/2014' and '29/07/2014'
```

If the date between two different Months .. the result is Null

For instance

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table Name 
WHERE date between '21/07/2014' and '1/08/2014'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using dates in SQL Server it pays to be explicit. In your second example it's likely SQL Server is converting the second date to 8th January 2014 as it will assume US style formatting like `mm/dd/yyyy`. I always write my date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format but it's probably better to use ISO8601 format as `YYYYMMDD` which (as marc_s points out) is a much more universal format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE date between '20140721' and '20140801'
```

Comment: Or even better: use the **ISO-8601** format which is `YYYYMMDD` (**no** dashes!) which works with **any** language and regional settings!

Comment: @marc_s or even better: don't use formats of any kind; dates do not have formats

Comment: @MarcGravell: true - if calling this T-SQL from e.g. C# code, use parameters with a `DateTime` type to avoid any string parsing. But if you're in T-SQL itself, you might have to define a date as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Dates don't have formats. Since you cite C#, it seems that this code is coming from a .NET caller - in which case, **parameterize**:

```
DateTime from = ..., to = ... // perhaps DateTime.Parse or DateTime.ParseExact,
                              // but perhaps DateTime.Now.Date.Add(...)
cmd.CommandText = @"
SELECT * 
FROM Table Name 
WHERE date between @from and @to";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("from", from);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("to", to);
```

Now there is no ambiguity whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ISO 8601 universal format. e.g. `'2007-04-05T14:30'`. It is interpreted regardless of locale settings.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use DD/MM/YY format that is style 103 if you convert, ie.

```
select *
from tbl
where dt between convert(date,'21/07/2014',103) and convert(date,'01/08/2014',103)
```

See fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f199c/6/0

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can also write you'r query like this

SELECT * 
FROM Table Name 
WHERE date between '21-Aug-2014' and '1-Sep-2014'